# Lookup filter on VF page

Tags: visualforce

I am using the custom lookup account search on VF page, Here I am trying to limit this lookup with few values, how should i achieve this using the `<inputText>` followed by 
`<apex:commandButton value="Lookup"` .. etc

**Note:** not using the account object

```
<apex:inputText title="Site" id="" style="width:175px" onkeypress="return noenter(event);"value="{!}" list="" onchange="();return false;"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Lookup" id="Button1" onclick="";return false;" />   
<apex:outputLabel value="" />
```

Comment: You can put all your conditions in the query which you fire to show results on the lookup vf page.

Comment: If this lookup is an existing field on that object, you can simply add a filter on that field and your lookup will be filtered dynamically. If not can you provide some code on what you have?

Comment: <apex:inputText title="Site" id="" style="width:175px" onkeypress="return noenter(event);"value="{!}" list="" onchange="();return false;"/><apex:commandButton value="Lookup" id="Button1" onclick="";return false;" />          
 <apex:outputLabel value="" />

Comment: Can you please be a little elaborate on what is the requirement and what you are up-to?

Comment: I am trying to update my current VF page with new functionality on lookup, I need to limit few values on lookup , I tried picklist as one of the option however that is not suitable for my requirement, here I want to limit the lookup search with only those 5 values. how can I achieve this? Hope this helps? For Eg: When I try to search for values in lookup I just want the results to be one of those 5 results. Thanks